# How to count multiple string length

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I have a String like that:

**Hey my name is $name$; I have $years$ years old, and I love play $sport$ and I live in $country$ !**

And I want to return the length of each word between $ in a Map, for my exemple the map should be:

- name -> 4
- years -> 5
- sport -> 5
- country -> 7

At first I thought about making recursive calls in my function, but I don't found a way to do that ?

Comment: Are you asking how to extract the strings `$name$`, `$years$`, etc?

Comment: Not really how to extract, but how to get the length of these strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can match using [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) this will return all matching instances, then you can iterate over the results and add to map.

```
String x = "Hey my name is $name$; I have $years$ years old," + 
           "and I love play $sport$ and I live in $country$ !";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\w+\\$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

while(m.find()) {
  String in = m.group().substring(1,m.group().length()-1);
  map.put(in, in.length());
}
```

Comment: This only matches a single character within the dollars `$a$` and the map will ignore duplicates which might not be desirable.

Comment: And the results are not the words `name`, `years`, etc. but `Hey my name is ` and `; I have `

Comment: Surprisingly the result is quite weird: it's missing one result and the other are in disarray. When I print my map the result is:
country -> 7
sport -> 5
years -> 5

Comment: 1 more edit to the new solution `\\w*` should be `\\w+`

Comment: @ClementCuvillier for me it prints country 7, name 4, sports 5, years 5

Comment: @EduardoDennis Yep with your edit, but it's not in the good order. It should be name 4 sport 5 years 5 and country 7

Comment: @ClementCuvillier take a look at my new edit, if order is important you have to use linkedhashmap

Comment: A map does not guarantee any ordering.  If you require ordering based on insertion order I suggest you use something else.

Comment: @jnbbender linkedhashmap does, Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

Remember that maps don't allow duplicates.... if that is ok for you then using streams and regex you can get that:

```
String x = "Hey my name is $name$; I have $years$ years old, and I love play $sport$ and I live in $country$ !";
//regex to get the words between $
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$(.*?)\\$").matcher(x);
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
//place those matchs in a list
while (m.find()) {
        l.add(m.group(1));
    }
System.out.println(l);
//collect those into a Map
Map<String, Integer> result = l.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(q -> q, q -> q.length()));

System.out.println(result);
```

your map can look like:

> {country=7, name=4, sport=5, years=5}

Comment: No need for `group(1)`, you can just use `group()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex like

*(.).*\1*

to search for words that begin and end with the same character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use streams.

```
public void test() {
    String s = "Hey my name is $name$; I have $years$ years old, and I love play $sport$ and I live in $country$ !";
    // Helps me maintain state of whether we are in a word or not.
    // Use AtomicBoolean as a `final` mutable value.
    final AtomicBoolean inWord = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    // Split on the `$` character and stream it.
    Map<String, Integer> myMap = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\$"))
            // Filter out the non-words (i.e. every other one).
            .filter(w -> inWord.getAndSet(!inWord.get()))
            // Generate the map.
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(w -> w, w -> String::length));
    System.out.println(myMap);
}
```

Prints:

> {country=7, name=4, sport=5, years=5}